# passing option value to php without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been looking for solution for my problem, but without any success. I have an HTML form with select element for selecting rooms, e.g.:

```
<select name="room" id="room">
<option value="MATH-1">MATH-1</option>
<option value="CHEM-3">CHEM-3</option>
<option value="LAB-04">LAB-04</option>
</select>
```

and later in the form I have a range element for selecting number of people:

```
<input type="range" name="personCount" id="personCount" min="1" max="20">
```

Information about rooms (name and capacity) are stored in mySQL database. What I want to do is to set max. value in the range element to value loaded from database (number 20 is just an example) and each time the room selector is changed, I also want to change max. value in the range element. 
I know how to get value from the selector (probably by using javascript) and I also know how to get room capacity from the database when I already know room's name, but I don't know how to combine  javascript with php. My idea how it should look is something like this:

```
<input type="range" name="personCount" id="personCount" min="1" max="<?php getRoomCapacity($roomName); ?>">
```

I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: ajax is what you're looking for if you have to do it via DB, but how many rooms is there ? maybe preloading arrays with one call to the db then using JS to change the input on select change

Comment: `max="<?php echo getRoomCapacity($roomName); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamically, you can use AJAX. If you're using jQuery, you can do it like this:

javascript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // when room is changed 
    $("#room").change(function() {
       var room = $("#room").val();

       // use AJAX to call php for getting room capacity
       $.post("getroomcapacity.php", 

           { room: room }, 

           function(data) {
               // set max attribute with the data we got from getroomcapacity.php
               $("#personCount").attr("max", data.max);

       });
    }); 
});
```

getroomcapacity.php:

```
<?php
$room = $_POST['room'];

$max = 20; // you get this value from db

echo json_encode(array('max' => $max));
```